# Dot Matrix Printing: Webpage

Tags: html, css, matrix, printing, dot-matrix

I have a problem printing a web page via google chrome in Dot Matrix Printer. I have configured all, but it is not showing the proper format. It is somehow **larger** than the default format.

Here is a non Dot-Matrix Printer. Like saving as PDF, it is showing correctly.

[image: Non Dot-Matrix]

Now, Here is the page when the Dot-Matrix Printer is selected. I am using **EPSON LX-310**

[image: The Dot Matrix]

I have tried saving it as PDF and printing it, it worked fine

[image: PDF]

For my instance, I have tried modifying the CSS, however, still, same problem.
I also reconfigured the paper size, yet, same problem. I cannot afford to save it as PDF, and print it since it would be so much hassle. Any conclusions?

If you ask for the CSS,

```
    @media print {
    body, html {
        display: block;
    }
    th {
        font-size: 13px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    td {
        font-size: 13px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        font-weight: lighter !important;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 22px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    thead th {
        padding: 0px !important;
    }

    @page {
        size: a4;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you go around it? Did you solve it?